# Android release version runs wild

Tags: android, android-studio

My app is fully tested in the debug version and functioning properly. The release version on the other hand crashes. Therefore, I have taken steps to debug the release version (BuildType Release: debuggable true). Now I can see that the app calls onCreateView for a segment, that is not loaded at start. Inside this onCreateView I go step by step and can see, that the program makes a step inside another function (Yes, not at the beginning but somewhere in the middle). Therefore I have written "run wild".

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        Signed {
            keyAlias 'xxx-certificate'
            keyPassword 'aaaaaaaaa'
            storeFile file('E:/_Arbeiten/AndroidStudioProjects/KeyStore/xxxKeystore')
            storePassword '9999999'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Signed
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "test_version", "No"
            debuggable true
        }
        debug {
            resValue "string", "test_version", "Yes"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        German {
            applicationId "de.xxx.android.xxxDict.DE"
            versionCode 25
            versionName "3.0"
        }

        English {
            applicationId "de.xxx.android.xxxDict.EN"
            versionCode 25
            versionName "3.0"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':lvl')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
}
```

I have tried until now:

1. remove minifyEnabled and proguardFiles from Release - same problem
2. insert signingConfig also for Debug and test this version - that works

I've also restarted Android Studio and cleaned the project several times. The problem remains. The release version is absolutely not function correctly.

I know that compileSdkVersion 23 is not the newest, but if I use version 24 I have a lot of other problems.

Fact: Debug works correctly (signed or not signed)
Fact: The release version crashes immediately at startup

Have someone an idea what happens?

EDIT: In the LogCat I see the following (Program Malibu):

```
I/ActivityManager(  913): Start proc de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE for activity de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/de.Malibu.dictionary.MainActivity: pid=192
39 uid=10141 gids={50141, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=x86
I/ActivityManager(  913): Launched start pid= [ 19239]
I/ActivityManager(  913): START u0 {cmp=de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/de.Malibu.dictionary.ExpDownloaderActivity} from uid 10141 on display 0
W/ActivityManager(  913): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2d4fbe19 u0 de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/de.Malibu.dictionary.MainActivity t465}
I/ActivityManager(  913): Launched start pid= [ -1]
I/ActivityManager(  913): Launched start pid= [ 19239]
D/ConnectivityService(  913): listenForNetwork for NetworkRequest [ id=122, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
D/ConnectivityService(  913): handleRegisterNetworkRequest checking NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 103]
D/ConnectivityService(  913): apparently satisfied.  currentScore=100
E/AndroidRuntime(19239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19239): Process: de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE, PID: 19239
E/AndroidRuntime(19239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/de.Malibu.dictionary.MainActivity}: ja
va.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(19239):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
E/AndroidRuntime(19239):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
I/ActivityManager(  913): Start proc com.google.android.apps.plus for service com.google.android.apps.plus/.service.EsSyncAdapterService: pid=19282 uid=10099 gids={50099,
9997, 3003, 3002, 1028, 1015} abi=x86
W/ResourcesManager(19282): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
I/ActivityManager(  913): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2: pid=19309 uid=10025 gids={50025, 9997, 3
003, 1028, 1015, 1023} abi=x86
I/ActivityManager(  913): Killing 19072:com.asus.email:exchange/u0a9 (adj 15): empty #9
W/libprocessgroup(  913): failed to open /acct/uid_10009/pid_19072/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
I/ActivityManager(  913): Killing 19049:com.asus.email/u0a9 (adj 15): empty #9
W/libprocessgroup(  913): failed to open /acct/uid_10009/pid_19049/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
W/ActivityManager(  913): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{2d4fbe19 u0 de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/de.Malibu.dictionary.MainActivity t465 f}
W/ActivityManager(  913): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{26c581db u0 de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/de.Malibu.dictionary.ExpDownloaderActivity t465
f}
D/TaskPersister(  913): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=465_task.xml
D/BatteryService(  913): Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.  level:93, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4211, temperature: 369, technology: Li-ion, AC po
wered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, dock AC powered:false, dock status:1, dock level:0, pad AC powered:false, pad status:1, pad level:0, pack AC powered
:false, pack status:1, pack level:0, icon:17303371, invalid charger:0
D/PowerUI ( 1043): dismiss Low BatteryWarning  level: 93
D/PowerUI ( 1043): show_hot_plug_dialog: true
D/PowerUI ( 1043): show_otg_cable_dialog: true
D/PowerUI ( 1043): plugged:true mBatteryStatus:2 mBatteryLevel: 93 mOldQcLevel: 0 mQcLevel:0 mShowCharingReminder:false
W/InputMethodManagerService(  913): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2d069398 attribute=null, token
= android.os.BinderProxy@14bd55eb
I/ActivityManager(  913): Process de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE (pid 19239) has died
W/ActivityManager(  913): App Op not allow to restart app de.Malibu.android.MalibuDict.DE/10141
```

Please remember what I said:
The Programm calls onCreateView of a segment that should not be loaded at start. It is a detail view which is later opened after a click in a list.

When I make my release version debuggable and set a breakpoint on onCreateView, then I can single step until line 32. The next step goes to line 78!Isn't that crazy?

Here is my onCreateView (I have only added the two mentioned line numbers 32 and 78):

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailview, container, false);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state
            mIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("Index");
            mLexItemList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("List");
        }

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        btnSpeaker = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSpeaker);
        btnSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mIndex < mLexItemList.size()) {
                    btnSpeaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_i);
                    btnSpeaker.setEnabled(false);
                    mLexItemList.get(mIndex).Sprechen(onSprechenFertig);
                }
            }
        });
        btnSpeaker.setImageResource(R.drawable.speaker_i);
        btnSpeaker.setEnabled(false);
        btnMemo = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnMemo);
        btnMemo.setEnabled(false);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        btnBack = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnBack.setEnabled(false);
        if (bundle != null) {
32            if (bundle.getInt("Memo", 0) == 1) {
                btnMemo.setEnabled(true);
                btnMemo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String suchwort;
                        int setSound=0;
                        LexItem lexItem = mLexItemList.get(mIndex);

                        HistoryDatabase db = new HistoryDatabase(getActivity());

                        if (mSuchwort.equals(""))
                            suchwort = lexItem.getThai();
                        else
                            suchwort = mSuchwort;
                        if (suchwort.substring(0, 2).equals("* ")) {
                            suchwort = suchwort.substring(2);
                        } else if (suchwort.substring(0, 2).equals("+ ")) {
                            suchwort = suchwort.substring(2);
                        }
                        String lang = "";
                        switch (lexItem.getLexTyp()) {
                            case ltDeutschThai: lang = "Text"; break;
                            case ltThaiDeutsch: lang = "Thai"; break;
                            case ltThaiumschriftDeutsch: lang = "Trans"; break;
                        }
                        String detail = lexItem.getBeschreibung();
                        if (detail.indexOf("*:;") > 0)
                            setSound++;
                        if ((detail.substring(0, 1).equals("*")) | (detail.substring(0, 1).equals("+"))) {
                            detail = detail.substring(1);
                        }
                        db.saveHistory(-1, lang, suchwort, lexItem.getThai(), lexItem.getLautschriftRoh(),
                                detail, lexItem.getVoicedatei(), setSound);

                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.memosave, Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                        t.show();
                    }
                });
            }
            if (mLexItemList.size() > 1) {
                if (bundle.getInt("Next", 0) == 1) {
                    btnNext.setEnabled(true);
                    btnNext.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_next_a);
                    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (mIndex < mLexItemList.size() - 1) {
78                              mIndex++;
                                refreshView();
                                setSelection(mIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (bundle.getInt("Back", 0) == 1) {
                    btnBack.setEnabled(true);
                    btnNext.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_previous_a);
                    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (mIndex > 0) {
                                mIndex--;
                                refreshView();
                                setSelection(mIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
```

And again: This problem is only on the release version, not in debug version! Therefore the code must be ok and the problem is maybe in the gradle?

Comment: What's the error message with the crash?

Comment: I can't see any error message.

Comment: Do you know how to view logcat? There should always be a message with a crash.

Comment: I've added today the LogCat output. Sorry, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Here's the problem: `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference` Look up what a nullpointerexception is and how to fix it.

Comment: The NullPointerException happens in android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity. I made a search for that in Google and found some reasons, but nothing regarding to my problem. My MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity. Someone recommends to use Activity instead, but I need the Compat version. Do you think that it is related to that?

Comment: Not really sure then, sorry.